# moving an image on a line generated by an angle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

hey guys i am taking an angle input from user and using it to stroke the line in that
direction

```
       function makeline(angle)
       {
       context.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);

          angle=document.getElementById("radi").value;
           //alert(angle);
          angle=(Math.PI/180)*angle;
         //getting end coordinates

           x2= 0+theCanvas.width*Math.cos(angle) //here angle should be in radians
           y2=400+theCanvas.width *Math.sin(angle);

           context.beginPath();
           context.setLineDash([3,2]);
           context.lineWidth=10;
           context.strokeStyle="black";
           context.moveTo(400,400);
           context.lineTo(x2,y2);
           context.stroke();
         }
```

now is it possible to move an image on the line that is generated every time with the new angle. Please help. take the image of a car or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can already work out where to draw the image using simple trigonometry. What you need to do is look into how to draw an image with arbitrary rotation onto a canvas.

Here's a quick sample of drawing a line of variable length and angle to a canvas. Add to it the results of your research into drawing rotated images and you're done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    byId('angleSlider').addEventListener('change', onSliderChange, false);
    byId('lengthSlider').addEventListener('change', onSliderChange, false);
}

function onSliderChange(evt)
{
    var slider = this;
    var tgtSpan = slider.nextSibling;
    tgtSpan.innerHTML = slider.value;
    drawCurValues();
}

function drawCurValues()
{
    var angle = byId('angleSlider').value;
    var displacement = byId('lengthSlider').value;

    var originX = 128, originY = 128;   // center of 256x256 canvas
    var can = byId('outputCanvas');
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width, can.height);

    var xOfs, yOfs;
    yOfs = displacement * Math.sin( angle * 3.141/180 );
    xOfs = displacement * Math.cos( angle * 3.141/180 );

    yOfs *= -1;     // since canvas 0,0 is at top-left, rather than bottom-left. 90 deg should be above origin, not below it
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(originX,originY);
    ctx.lineTo( originX+xOfs, originY+yOfs );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

</script>
<style>
canvas
{
    border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    Angle <input type='range' value='0' min='0' max='360' id='angleSlider'/><span id='angleDisplay'></span><br>
    Length <input type='range' value='0' min='0' max='181' id='lengthSlider'/><span id='lengthDisplay'></span><br> <!-- 181 = sqrt(2) * 128; i.e dist from center to corners of canvas -->
    <canvas width='256' height='256' id='outputCanvas'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u please explain this code. i am unable to understand it.

Comment: Which part of it is presenting you with a problem? I'll try to do my best.

Comment: actually this is not the scenario i am talking about.

Comment: ????? I don't understand what you're referring to. Consider providing more detail..

Comment: i want the user to enter an angle in a text box. retrieve the vaue out of text box then generate a line based on that angle and after that use drawimage() method to move an image over that from origin to the end of line creating an animation using maybe an animation frame .please enlighten me in this context. thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, I understand this and did so from your original question - though the animation part is new. Like I said earlier, you need to research how to draw a rotated image (Hint: the canvas is translated then rotated, the image is drawn and then the canvas is un-rotated and un-translated). You would also need to research some basic animation functionality - either with a call to SetTimeout or RequestAnimationFrame (preffered). Since you can calculate the start and end-points, and how long the move should take, you can calculate the deltaX and deltaY for each frame. There's lots of tuts around..

Comment: yes.indeed..neways thank you so much. appreciate it.